# Remove JSON node in java

Tags: java, json

I try to delete all nodes of an arbitrary JSON, which have a value of 'null'.

Somehow I struggled with JsonPath therefore I tried to iterate through the JSON with the following code:

```
public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
    while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
        String key = keysItr.next();
        Object value = object.get(key);

        if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
            value = toList((JSONArray) value);
        }

        else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
            value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
        }
        map.put(key, value);
        if(value.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("NULL")) {
            object.remove(key);
        }
    }
    return map;
}

public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        Object value = array.get(i);
        if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
            value = toList((JSONArray) value);
        }

        else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
            value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
        }
        list.add(value);
    }
    return list;
}
```

When I run it over my JSON, then then the not the whole element is deleted, as the brackets stay. Also I wonder, if it would work, if I have the same name of a key at two different places, but only want to remove one.

> before: {"interests":[{"interestKey1":"Dogs"},{"interestKey2":"Cats"},{"interestKey3":null}]}
>
> after: {"interests":[{"interestKey1":"Dogs"},{"interestKey2":"Cats"},{}]}

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

you are removing the key-value pair from JsonObject and not the enclosing JsonArray.  And a JsonObject can have several key-value pair in itself.  So deleting one doesn't delete the whole object.

```
jsonObj={"a":"cde","b":"fgh"}
```

this is a valid jsonObject.  when I delete "b" from it like `jsonObj.remove("b")`, only "a" remains `{"a":"cde"}` and deleting "a" returns `{}`

Hence, if you want to remove the whole jsonObject from jsonArray, remove it directly from jsonArray.

And in JsonArray, you can't select a jsonObject with key and rather with its index.  Hence, even when it has two JsonObjects with same keys, you have to select one by their unique index.

Answer (score 0):

Try to handle base case for object.
It's below code might be help:

```
public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws 
JSONException {

    if(object==null)return null;   
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
    while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
    String key = keysItr.next();
    Object value = object.get(key);

    if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
        value = toList((JSONArray) value);
    }

    else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
        value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
    }
    if(null != value)
       map.put(key, value);
    if(null==value || value.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("NULL")) {
        object.remove(key);
    }
   }
 return map;
}
```